# How can I find the uncertainty of derivatives?

Tags: least-squares, uncertainty, derivative

Suppose I have a quadratic (weighted) least-square fit result obtained from a given set of data:

$$
f(x) = \underbrace{-0.243(\pm0.3324)}_{quad\_a}x^2\underbrace{-0.921(\pm0.061)}_{quad\_b}x\underbrace{-2.12(\pm0.0223)}_{quad\_c}
$$
If I'm taking the derivative of $f(x)$ to have $f'(x) = Ax+B$, I wonder how can I figure out the uncertainties on $A$ and $B$? I also have the correlations

```
C(quad_a, quad_c) = -0.422
C(quad_a, quad_b) = -0.278
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Because $(A,B)$ is a known linear combination of the three fitted coefficients, all you need do is apply the (standard) formula for the variance of a linear combination.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the comment! Is that $Var(aX+bY) = a^2Var(X) +b^2Var(Y) + 2abCov(X,Y)$ I'm still  confused how to find the uncertainties of $A$ and $B$ from that.

Comment: The duplicate asks exactly the same question and gives explicit formulas for the answer.  All you have to do is plug in your particular values.